# Django create connected objects simultaneously

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm new to Django and wanted to ask how can I solve a problem that I have

```py
class InventoryId(models.Model):
    inventory_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Laptop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    inventory_id = models.ForeignKey(InventoryId, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Desktop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    inventory_id = models.ForeignKey(InventoryId, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In the example above I would like models `Laptop` and `Desktop` to use inventory_id's that are stored in the same table and are incremental to avoid collisions.

example:

```
laptop1 --> inventory_id = 1
desktop1 --> inventory_id = 2
laptop2 --> inventory_id = 3
```

what's the correct way of doing that in django?

I found something that recommends using signals to do that. but i was discouraged by documentation that it may be not the best idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [*model inheritance* <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) instead:

```
class InventoryItem(models.Model):
    inventory_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)


class Laptop(InventoryItem):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Desktop(InventoryItem):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

This will make `OneToOneField`s from `Laptop` and `Desktop` to the table of the `InventoryItem`.

It also guarantees that two `Desktop`s for example can not refer to the same `InventoryItem.

Since you here, perhaps as an example, have two `name` fields with the same specifications, it makes sense to "pull up" this field to the `InventoryItem` model.

Answer (score 0):

Is there something particular you believe that would make this not work as is?

The id of a model instance is always going to be unique. So using the id of a InventoryId object seems fine to me.

There's always djangos UUID field though if you feel you need it.